# How to send message using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm new using python and telegram-bot

I'm trying to found a way to send messages using python-telegram-bot when I received a message without uses:

```
requests.post(
        'https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<id>&text=Hello World!')
```

Flow:

Message arrived on channel A then send a new message to channel B (Message receveid on Channel A).

I only found reply_text. Is there other way to do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`reply_text` won't work because it will send the message back to channel A. You would need [bot.send_message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message) where you can set the target channel with `chat_id`. A simple example:

```
def update_message_to_channel_B(update: object, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHANNEL_B_ID, text='Message receveid on Channel A')
```

And add the handler:

```
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, update_message_to_channel_B))
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply ! I found that bot is on context like:

context.bot.send_message

Comment: Correct, see my example.